# Using Bigquery.Dataset.Patch to update access

Tags: google-bigquery

we want to programmatically patch the access field of the Dataset and add an user. Patch semantics for array indicate override, so we need to provide the full contents of the access field. How do we avoid race conditions caused by read-modify-write? The API doesn't seem to provide conflict detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to avoid race conditions caused by multiple users modifying the dataset acl simultaneously. In general, dataset acls change slowly enough that we haven't found this to be a problem. Patch semantics should, however protect you against simultaneous modification of other fields, such as the dataset description.